# Regular Expression: how to match 'ab','ac' and 'a'

Tags: regex, grep

Now, I have three strings to be matched by a single re -- 'a', 'ab','ac'
I suppose one correct re should be 'a[bc]?', but it seems not correct. What is the correct one?

I try it in grep command. And it seems that there is no '?' in grep's regex. So how to do this matching in grep?

Thanks to @anubhava, I now can match all these three strings by:

```
grep -E 'a[bc]?' <file>
```

However, this expression also matches 'ad'.

In fact, I want to match all these situation:
'a','abc','ab','ac'
but do not want to match 'ad' or 'ae'

Comment: It matches `'ad'` because it matches `'a'`; did you try using the word boundaries as anubhava suggested?

Comment: @EarthWorm: My suggested command was `grep -E "\ba[bc]?\b" file` (note extra word boundaries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use above in a grep command then use extended regex support switch `-E` with word boundaries:

```
grep -E "\ba[bc]?\b" file
```

OR

```
grep -E "\<a[bc]?\>" file
```

Answer (score 3):

To use this expression in basic mode, you need to escape the question mark:

```
grep 'a[bc]\?' file
```

**Update**

To address your latest question, I would advice using P(erl) mode:

```
grep -P 'a(?![de])|a[bc]|abc'
```

These are the alternations:

1. Match an 'a' if not followed by 'd' or 'e' (it uses negative look-ahead)
2. Match 'ab' or 'ac'
3. Match 'abc'

Answer (score 2):

If you want the string to match the regex from beginning to end, you need to include in the regex the start `^` and end `$` markers

```
^a[bc]?$
```

If the markers are not part of the regex `123ab456` will match the regex.